# Should this throw a KeyError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been practicing some algorithmic questions and came across the following excerpt the other day in Python 3:

```
for i, num in enumerate(nums):
   n = target - num
   if n not in h:
      h[num] = i
```

Shouldn't this code throw a KeyError since `h[num]` is not defined? I thought that when this occurs, we need to use `collections.defaultdict()` to prevent a KeyError.

I came across this piece before and it uses the `defaultdict` to avoid KeyErrors as the author states, but I don't see the difference between them here.

```
targets = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for a, b in sorted(tickets)[::-1]:
      targets[a] += b,
```

Comment: No, why should it? You're setting a new value in the dict, not trying to get a nonexistent one.

Comment: I came across this piece before and it uses the defaultdict to avoid KeyErrors as the author states, but I don't see the difference between them here.

`targets = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for a, b in sorted(tickets)[::-1]:
        targets[a] += b,
`

Comment: In this case, the author accesses the list `target[a]` in order to extend it. Using a `defaultdict(list)` makes sure that an empty list will be created as the value corresponding to the key `a` if it hasn't been set before.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much that clears everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is different from your first.

In your first, you're just setting a key/value pair. In your second however, you're *getting the previous value*, then reassigning back to the key.

```
targets[a] += b
```

Could be thought of as being broken down to

```
old_value = targets[a]  # This will raise a key error if `a` doesn't exist already
targets[a] = old_value + b  # This will never raise an error
```

Your first example is like the second line. A plain overwrite is always fine. The `targets` example requires looking up a previous value though. With a normal dictionary, that will cause a `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist. With a default dictionary though, it's fine, since a default value is supplied.